# How to update the return URL for Apple SignIn after creating the identifier/key

Tags: ios, apple-sign-in

I'm trying to figure out where to go to update the return URL for signin with Apple, I already have a key and identifier created for it and now when I try to edit either it doesn't give me the option to change the return URL.

I tried deleting the identifier but got an error stating "The bundle 'XXXXXXXX' cannot be deleted. Delete all the Apps related to this bundle to proceed." - but not sure what they mean by apps related to this bundle, and I deifnitely don't want to delete the app I created just to unassociate signin and then reassociate it with new return URLs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Figured out the issue, Apples 'Identifiers' URL has pretty bad UX, I had to click on the dropdown called 'App IDS' and select 'Services IDS' to bring up the services and update the return URL.

Answer (score 2):

On the Identifiers page on the right top corner click on dropdown and select "**Services ID's**". Now you will be able to change a return URL.
[Choosing Services ID's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2orM0.png)

Comment: This duplicates the original answer and adds no new content. The original poster was the chosen answer, so the question has most definitely been solved. Your new answer repeats the actions described in the original answer, thus adding nothing new. In the future, please consider when a question is posted and if it has an answer when deciding to post, as well.

Comment: @BenA. I added a picture, that is better describe what needs to be done.